# lldb equivalent to (gdb) set target-charset?

Tags: lldb

In gdb I can switch between different character set encodings (ASCII and EBCDIC say) using commands like:

```
(gdb) set target-charset EBCDIC

(gdb) set target-charset ASCII
```

Does lldb have this sort of functionality (perhaps undocumented)?

If not, looking at the advanced python integration available in lldb, I'd guess the best way to implement this would be with a python method.  Would anybody be able to point me to a sample python script where the display of a given type is specialized that I could adapt in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a feature, lldb assumes ASCII.

You can add a custom summary from Python to present values of a given type any way you want.  This is discussed here:

http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html

There are a handful of summary examples here:

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/lldb/examples/summaries

and you'll also want to consult the SB API documentation, which is here:

http://lldb.llvm.org/python_reference/index.html